# Returning a generic object with a bound parameter in java

Tags: java, generics, collections

This question has probably been asked in various fashions but its quite hard to search for a problem you don't know the name of. So here is the simplest approach:

```
class Digestable {}
class Mouse extends Digestable {}
class Cat extends Animal<Mouse> {}

class Animal<T extends Digestable> {
    List<T> belly = new ArrayList<>();

     void eat(T a) {
        belly.add(a);
    }
}

class main {
    <T extends Digestable> Animal<T> returnAnimal() {
        return new Cat(); <--- compiler error!
    }
}
```

Why the compiler error? new Cat() literally satisfies the signature of returnAnimal() as well as the type T extends Digestable. Why can't the compiler check the types down the hirarchy?

Comment: It does not satisfy the parameter. Look again, `Cat` extends `Animal<Mouse>` but `T` can also be something other than `Mouse`.

Comment: @user264235 Imagine you tried: `Animal<Rat> a = returnAnimal()`, where `Rat` is a subclass of `Digestable`. What do you think should happen?

Answer (score 0):

Because a `Cat` is an `Animal<Mouse>` and the `returnAnimal` method returns an `Animal<T>`, with `T` being ***any*** descendant of `Digestable`. And in Java, an `Animal<Mouse>` is of different type than i.e. an `Animal<Zebra>`.

According to your example, this makes perfect sense, since an animal that eats mice (such as a cat) is totally different from an animal that eats zebras (such as a lion).

Comment: Thanks to all you pointed me into the right direction and helped me understand the difference of the type parameter `T` and the wildcard `?`. 

The intention of the `returnAnimal()` methods was: “I want to get from you an Animal that eats at least something Digestible”.

But the signature of `<T extends Digestible> Animal<T>` is not equivalent to “an Animal that eats at least something Digestible” but **`Animal<? extends Digestable>`** is. Using this the compiler does not complain.